# Is there a javascript library or native way to handle hashmaps with multi keys?

Tags: javascript, hash, hashmap

In javascript there is an object like {} where you can have keys, which are just 1 value. But in general if I want a hashmap where the key is multivalues like it could be 3 or 6 or 7 integers that map to a value, etc... If there a best way to handle it natively, or is there a library for it?

Thanks

Comment: Well, there's the newish Map class, but the basic problem for your application is that there's nothing in JavaScript like the `.hashValue()` and `.equals()` conventions in Java (for example). Thus, all you have to work with is the native equality comparison for determining key equality.

Comment: That is fine, the native equality is fine for comparing keys, since the keys are all integers anyways.

Comment: This is a classic [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/289905). What are you _actually_ trying to do? Why would you need such a hash map?

Comment: @omega no, it's not fine, because (at least according to the question) want keys to be compared with some custom process (multiple values). An entry in a Map has a *single* key. The key can be an object or an array, but comparison for equality is done (basically) with `===`.

Comment: just noticed that if I have a key as say [1,2,3,4], then getting it back won't work because [1,2,3,4] !== [1,2,3,4]. Is there a way I can get around that?

Comment: one way is compare stringified versions

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array with the numbers and join it by default with comma. Then take the string as key for an object.

```js
var hash = Object.create(null);

hash[[1, 2, 4, 5].join()] = 'foo';
console.log(hash[[1, 2, 4, 5].join()]);
hash[[1, 2, 4, 5].join()] = 'baz';
console.log(hash[[1, 2, 4, 5].join()]);
hash[[1, 2, 4, 5, 7].join()] = 'bar';
console.log(hash);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```